# Extract significant digit from 0.0007

Tags: python, digits

I want to extract significant digit of 7 from `XX=0.0007`

The code is as follows

```
XX=0.0007
enX1=XX//10**np.floor(np.log10(XX));
```

But `XX` becomes `6`not `7`. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what if `xx = 0.00054`

Comment: Don't use a double slash.

Answer (score 1):

In some sense, you were lucky to start out with the value `0.0007`. As it turns out, that value is one of the (many!) decimal values that cannot be represented *exactly* in a floating point format.

A floating point number gets usually stored in the common [IEEE-754 format](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) as powers of 2. Just like a whole number such as 175 is stored as the sum of bits with increasing powers-of-two values (165 = 128 + 32 + 4 + 1), fractions are stored as a sum of 1/power-of-two numbers. That means that a value of 1/2, 1/4, and 1/65536 can be stored exactly (and sums thereof, such as 3/4), but your `0.0007` can *not*. Its closest value is actually 0.0000699999999999999992887633748495. ("Closest" in the sense that adding just one more one-bit at the end will make it slightly *larger* than 0.0007, and the difference is ever so slightly larger than this lower one.)

In your calculation, you use the double divide slash `//`, which instructs Python to do an integer division and *discard* the fractional part. So while the intermediate calculation is correct and you get something like `6.99999...`, this gets *truncated* and you end up with `6`.

If you use a *single* slash, the result will keep its (exact!) decimals but Python will *represent* it as `7.0000`, give or take a few zeroes. By default, Python displays only a small number of decimals.

Note that this still "is" not the exact value `7`. The calculation starts out with an imprecise number, and although there may be some intermediate rounding here and there, there is only a small chance you end up with a *precise* integer. Again, not for all decimals, but for a large number of them. Other fractional values may be stored fractionally *larger* than the value you enter – `0.0004`, for example<sup>a</sup> – but the underlying 'problem' of accuracy is also present there. It's just not as visible as with yours.

If you want a nearest integer result, use a single divide slash for the exact calculation, followed by `round` to force the number to the nearest integer anyway.

<sup>a</sup> To be precise, as somewhere about 0.000400000000000000019168694409544. After your routine, Python will *display* it as `4` but internally it's still just a bit larger than that.